# Entity Framework code throwing error when moved to Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an application that is running fine on my local computer (Win8). It is an ASP.NET MVC app which connects to a remote SQL Server 2012 database.

When I publish this site to a Windows 2012 Server the Entity Framework code throws the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The type of the key field
>   'EcdisTypeId' is expected to be '[removed...]EcdisTypeEnum', but the
>   value provided is actually of type 'System.Int32'. at
>   System.Data.EntityKey.ValidateTypeOfKeyValue(MetadataWorkspace
>   workspace, EdmMember keyMember, Object keyValue, Boolean
>   isArgumentException, String argumentName) at
>   System.Data.EntityKey.ValidateEntityKey(MetadataWorkspace workspace,
>   EntitySet entitySet, Boolean isArgumentException, String argumentName)
>   at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.CheckKeyMatchesEntity(IEntityWrapper
>           wrappedEntity, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySetForType, Boolean forAttach) at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddEntry(IEntityWrapper
>   wrappedObject, EntityKey passedKey, EntitySet entitySet, String
>   argumentName, Boolean isAdded) at
>   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func2
>   constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet) at
>   lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) at
>   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator1.ReadNextElement(Shaper
>   shaper) at
>   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
>   at ...

The code is exactly the same that runs fine on my machine. 'EcdisTypeId' is mapped to an `int` column in the DB, and to an Enum in code. I am using Entity Framework 5.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you please specify primary error, which you got as a output.

Comment: What do you mean? I already posted the exception.

Comment: Have you cast Ecdis TypeId in code. (i.e) (int)EcdisTypeId